# Are bad questions worth keeping for educational purposes?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

I noticed today that one of my old questions got a downvote ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297451/how-to-use-git-to-tag-a-commit-rather-than-a-hash)) which drew my attention back to it, and I can see now that it demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of the topic. Essentially, the question itself is wrong, and comments and answers have been posted explaining why this is.

I think that the question is still valuable to have on the site, because I suspect other people will also have the same misunderstanding, and reading the explanations here will help them. On the other hand, I can also see that it is a bad question, and therefore perhaps should not have been posted.

So, if a question is bad, but the explanation of why it is bad is helpful, does that make the question helpful and worth keeping?

Comment: So, your question is basically *"How can I avoid downvotes?"* How about just not worrying about them instead.

Comment: If you delete the last paragraph, that question may not have attracted the downvote. As it stands, the structure of the question forces the answers to be in the form of comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think people go to the faq and meta for this type of information.  Questions should have value in the context of a programming problem.  If the comments add this value, edit the question.  If not, consider deleting the question.